# Issue with Database

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I have two OS installed on my PC. windows XP and Win 7, XP has Visual Studio 2008(SQL Sever  2005) and 7 has V.S.2010 (SQL Server 2008).

i code a website in XP with 2008 (MS SQL Server 2005 database), and once i opened that project in VS 2010, that asked me to convert code etc. and i did so and then again when i am trying to open the database on VS 2008, i can't.

it's show a error message.

> The database 'c:\abc.MDF' cannot be opened because it is version 655. This server supports version 612 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.
>   Could not open new database 'c:\abc.MDF' .
>   CREATE DATABASE is aborted.
>   An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file c:\abc.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just Googled this and here is the first result: [http://conceptdev.blogspot.com/2009/04/mdf-cannot-be-opened-because-it-is.html](http://Result)

He suggests:

> To fix the problem, go to Tools →
>   Options... → Database Tools → Data
>   Connections and change the SQL Server
>   Instance Name from whatever it was
>   (probably a SQL Server 2005 instance)
>   to your SQL Server 2008 instance, hit
>   OK and you should be fine!